# Add click event on div tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` tag in my form without `id` property. I need to set an `on-click` event on this `div` tag.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="drill_cursor" >
....
</div>
```

I don't want to add an `id` property to my `div` tag.

**How can I add an `on-click` event on this tag using JavaScript?**

Answer (score 63, accepted):

#### Pure JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('drill_cursor')[0]
        .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            // do something
        });
```

#### jQuery

```
$(".drill_cursor").click(function(){
//do something
});
```

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
 var div = document.getElementsByClassName('drill_cursor')[0];

 div.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
     alert('Hi!');
 });
```

Answer (score 20):

Just add the onclick-attribute:

```
<div class="drill_cursor" onclick='alert("youClickedMe!");'>
....
</div>
```

It's javascript, but it's automatically bound using an html-attribute instead of manually binding it within `<script>` tags - maybe it does what you want.

While it might be good enough for very small projects or test pages, you should definitly consider using `addEventListener` (as pointed out by other answers), if you expect the code to grow and stay maintainable.

Comment: It is JavaScript! This is inline JavaScript code, and it really is widely adopted bad practice. It is hard to debug and maintain code, that is placed in various places over your html document. I recommend to use event handlers.

Comment: I upvote this one, because I needed a solution that could be used in a partial. The others required that I know the specific DIV I want to call the action on when clicked. My page has dynamic divs generated and I needed a way to call JS on an individual DIV when clicked. And I was not sure if you could call `onClick` on a DIV. Thank you!

Comment: The solution from @maja allowed me to check that it works. My `onClick` event is more like this: `onClick:"toggleReadStatus(" + cue.id.to_s + ")"` (RUBY code). So, speaking to @Andrew Surzhynskyi 's point, the JS code can be in a particular section for easy maintenance (and reduced repetition), but available to each dynamically generated DIV.

Answer (score 9):

Recommend you to use Id, as Id is associated to only one element while class name may link to more than one element causing confusion to add event to element.

try if you really want to use class:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('drill_cursor')[0].onclick = function(){alert('1');};
```

or you may assign function in html itself:

```
<div class="drill_cursor" onclick='alert("1");'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

the document class selector:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('drill_cursor')[0].addEventListener('click',function(){},false)
```

also the document query selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

```
document.querySelector(".drill_cursor").addEventListener('click',function(){},false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate function to make adding event handlers much easier.

```
function addListener(event, obj, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(event, fn, false);   // modern browsers
    } else {
        obj.attachEvent("on"+event, fn);          // older versions of IE
    }
}

element = document.getElementsByClassName('drill_cursor')[0];

addListener('click', element, function () {
    // Do stuff
});
```