# Need to hide the clicked div and reappear after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript

Need to hide the clicked div.

I tried with an example in jsfiddle. As i am new to js i want a better solution.

```
<div class="t1">1</div>
<div class="t2">2</div>
<div class="t3">3</div>
<div class="t4">4</div>
<div class="t5">5</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5Lh3yfov/

Comment: where is the link ??

Comment: @raj, when you say *better solution*, it implies that you have tried something and you want better than that.

Comment: Please refer [How to add click on div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772954/add-click-event-on-div-tag-using-javascript) and [How to execute a function after X seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252638/executing-javascript-after-x-seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pls find the working snippet added below

```js
$('body').on('click','.t11',function(){
    $(this).hide();
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        that.show();
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t1 t11">1</div>
<div class="t2 t11">2</div>
<div class="t3 t11">3</div>
<div class="t4 t11">4</div>
<div class="t5 t11">5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet.it works...

Answer (score 0):

do do something like,

```js
function hideAndShow(element, timeout){
  element.style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(function(){
      element.style.display = "block";
    },timeout);
}

hideAndShow(document.getElementById("myDiv"), 10000)
```

```css
div#myDiv{
  width:100px;
  background-color: #f00;
  height:100px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <div>
```

Comment: Thanks...it works too

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) method for that.

```js
// get all div and iterate over them 
// for newer browser you can use Array.from 
// to convert NodeList to array
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.t')).forEach(function(e) {
  // attach event listener to the element
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // hide the element
    this.style.display = 'none';
    // set timer
    setTimeout(function() {
      // show the element
      this.style.display = 'block';
      // bind the this context or you can use `e` 
    }.bind(this), 10000);
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="t">1</div>
<div class="t">2</div>
<div class="t">3</div>
<div class="t">4</div>
<div class="t">5</div>
```

Comment: Note: `Array.from` is a part of ES6 and is not implemented in all browsers. You can use `[].slice.call` as an alternate or just have a `for` loop

Comment: @Rajesh :  updated

Comment: Well it was a note for others who read it. It was just a caveat. Even I love `array.from`

Comment: Thanks...it works too